# How to select multiple photos?

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I can select one photo at a time, using a UIImagePickerController but I need to select more than one Photo Album using Xamarin?

```
    UIImagePickerController picker = new UIImagePickerController();
picker.AllowsEditing = false;
        picker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum;
        this.PresentModalViewController(picker, true);
```

Comment: the standard UIImagePickerControl does not allow for multiple selection.

Comment: Use [WSAssetsLibraryController](https://github.com/w5mith/WSAssetPickerController)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...there is ELCImagePickerController  which allows multiple images selection 
example

```
// Create the image picker
ELCImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initImagePicker];
imagePicker.maximumImagesCount = 4; //Set the maximum number of images to select, defaults to 4
imagePicker.returnsOriginalImage = NO; //Only return the fullScreenImage, not the fullResolutionImage
imagePicker.imagePickerDelegate = self;

//Present modally
[self presentViewController:elcPicker animated:YES completion:nil];

// Release if not using ARC
[imagePicker release];
```

Code can be found  [here](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController)!